# Combining a grouped bar plot with a truncated line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, linechart

I know how to create a [grouped bar plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) and I know how to create a [line plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) in matplotlib but unfortunately, I don't know how to combine both in a way that groups the line plots as well according to the bar groups, while preserving two axes. The following sketch (hopefully) illustrates what I try to achieve:

[image: Plot sketch]

And this is what I have done so far:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

YearGroup1 = ['G11','G12']
Unemployment_RateGroup1 = [31,32]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.plot(YearGroup1, Unemployment_RateGroup1)
plt.show()
```

However, I don't know how to reposition the x-positions of the line chart manually. The lines are supposed to be within groups and should be on the second y-axis.

The whole plot aims to show results for different algorithms (X_1,X_2,X_3,...) on different data types (red bar, green bar, blue bar). The grouped line charts on the second y-axis should represent the time needed for each algorithm.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can plot the bars and then plot the lines afterwards. x-positions for lines should be something like `[x1 - width, x1, x1 + width]` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I added an initial MWE to my question. However, I don't know how to move the xticks manually. How would your approach look like in code?

Comment: thanks for extending your question. What do you mean by "move the xticks"? Do you want to move the xtick labels, f.i. swap G1, G2 etc. or do you want to move the position of the labels? And what do you want to plot with the lines? Are the lines supposed to be **within groups**, f.i. show trends from men to women withing G1, or to **span multiple groups**, f.i. show the trend for men spanning groups G1 to G5?

Comment: Oh and what about the second y-axis? Are the lines supposed the be on the second y-axis?

Comment: I edited my question again to address your questions.

Comment: I honestly still don't get whether you want you lines to be *within groups* or to *span multiple groups*, but I assume you mean the former. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the line plot is supposed to display **within group** data, you can plot it like this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

YearGroup1 = ['G11','G12']
Unemployment_RateGroup1 = [31,32]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()  # <--- make a second y-axis
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

# plot lines    
for i in range(len(labels)):
    ax2.plot(
        [x[i] - width / 2, x[i] + width / 2], 
        Unemployment_RateGroup1, 
        color='C3', marker='+', mec='k'
    )

fig.tight_layout()
```

Please mind that I dropped `plt.show()`. If you require this line, don't forget to add it.

If you have separate data of `Unemployment_Rate` for each group, f.i.

```
Unemployment_Rate = [[31, 32], [7, 12], [23, 9], [0, 1], [32, 0]]
```

you can replace the line plotting with:

```
ax2.plot(
    [x[i] - width / 2, x[i] + width / 2], 
    Unemployment_Rate[i], 
    color='C3', marker='+', mec='k'
)
```

which will yield:
[image: Bars and within-group lines]